# Assigning value for a control which is in child page

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I have created a countdown timer function in javascript and the body tag onload event I am calling this function. But my problem is I want to display the time left thing in a label which is Child page. Is there a way to assign a control which is in child page from master page ?

Here is the function

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var tim;

    var min = 2;
    var sec = 0;

    function Timer() {
        if (min == 0 && sec == 0) {
            clearTimeout(tim);
            window.location.href = "Result.aspx";
        }
        else {
            if (sec < 1) {
                sec = 59;
                if (min > 0)
                    min = min - 1;
            }
            else
                sec = sec - 1;
            var mins = "", secs = "";
            if (min <= 9)
                mins = "0" + min;
            else
                mins = min;
            if (sec <= 9)
                secs = "0" + sec;
            else
                secs = sec;
            document.getElementById("lblTimer1").innerHTML = "Time Left : " + mins + " : " + secs;
            tim = setTimeout("Timer()", 1000);
        }
    }
</script>
```

I'm calling Timer() in body onload event and lblTimer1 is the label control which is in child page.
Thanks,
Nuthan Gowda

Comment: there are many ways if show us your attempts..

Comment: I need to show the function which I have written ?

Comment: yes,no body gives you answer if you dont do it..

Comment: So you want to have a client-side JavaScript timer tell the master page (server-side) to update a label on a content page (server-side) on an interval? Do I have that right?

Comment: Actually I'm not so much used to javascript. I was looking up for a countdown timer in internet and I got this function. This works fine for a single page. But My project is of a master page one. So the body tag was in master page. So I was trying is there any option to over come.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are sure you won't run into conflicting ids, depending on your framework version, most simple way is setting `ClientIDMode="Static"` on your label. Your code should then work.

If not sure, you may set a (unique) utility cssclass of 'timerLabel' on your label, then in your function :

```
document.getElementsByClassName("timerLabel")[0].innerHTML = "Time Left : " + mins + " : " + secs;
```

Comment: I am getting a error called "Object doesnt support poperty or method 'getElementByClassName' "

Comment: @NuthanGowda oups, my fault : getElementsByClassName (with an 's' at the end of 'Element')

Comment: Unable to set a value of the property innerHTML: Object is null or undefined,,